# generics multiple types

Tags: java, generics

Defining a method as

```
myMethod(Object... obj){}
```

allows arbitrary number and types of parameters to be used.

I'd love to use generics for strict definition of the number and types of parameters.

For example, Let's assume that the above mentioned `myMethod(Object...)` is a method in a class named `MyClass` and `MyClass` can be instantiated by default constructor.

I need to define instances in a way similar to this:

```
MyClass<Integer, Integer, String> instance1 = new MyClass<Integer, Integer, String>();
MyClass<String, String, Integer, Integer> instance2 = new MyClass<String, String, Integer, Integer>();
```

so the type definitions above will set the number and types of parameters allowed on calls to `myMethod()`:

```
instance1.myMethod(1, 2, "test");
instance2.myMethod("one", "two", 1, 2);
```

The question is: How to define `MyClass` in such a way that will allow **any** number of type parameters?

Any advice will be appreciated.

Comment: What would you do with these parameters in `myMethod()`?

Comment: The purpose is to decorate an implementation of <code>java.sql.PreparedStatement</code> in such a way that an instantiation of the decorated class will contain the definition of the parameters required for a SQL query.

Comment: It is probably not useful to substitute one prepared statement with another that just happens to have the same argument types. Better to go for stronger typed interfaces that have some defined purpose and meaning.

Answer (score 4):

You can't, number of type parameters is fixed per class. you can play crazy tricks

```
class Tuple
{ 
    Object[] objects() { return ...; }
}
class Tuple1 ...
class Tuple2 ...
class Tuple3<T1,T2,T3> extends Tuple
{
    static public<S1,S2,S3> Tuple3<S1,S2,S3> of(S1 o1, S2 o2, S3 o3){ return ...; }
}
class Tuple4<T1,T2,T3,T4> extends Tuple
{
    static public<S1,S2,S3,S4> Tuple4<S1,S2,S3,S4> of(S1 o1, S2 o2, S3 o3, S4 o4){ return ... ; }
}
...
class Tuple9 ...

class MyClass<TupleN extends Tuple>
{
    void myMethod(TupleN ntuple)
    {
        Object[] objects = ntuple.objects();
        // work on objects
    }
}

MyClass<Tuple3<Integer,Integer,String>> instance3 = new MyClass<Tuple3<Integer, Integer, String>>();
instance3.myMethod( Tuple3.of(1,2,"test") );
```

It's **not worth it**. Sometimes you have to give up extraneous type checking for simplicity.

Comment: now I kind of like this tuple idea, your fault! The `of` methods can all be moved into `Tuple` class to write `Tuple.of(1,2,"test")`

Comment: So far this seems to be the best option and I'll examine using it. If I do I will accept this answer.

What's the purpose?! I have a useful (so I think) decoration of java.sql.PreparedStatement which can be used in the following way: 

    aPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(param1, param2, param3);

and I want the parameters given to this method to be constrained by the instance declaration, similar to what is done with generic types.

Comment: well, why declare a type safe instance `stmtBlah`, while you can declare an old fashion method, which is of course type safe, `updateBlah(Integer,Integer,String)`.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think what you're trying to do can be achieved, but perhaps you could give some indication of what `myMethod()` does?

Answer (score 3):

What's the point?  I can't imagine a scenario where this would be useful, and be the best solution available.  I'm not trying to be derogatory, but it's worth mentioning that you should subscribe to the [KISS principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle).  Sounds like you're falling victim to over-engineering, and it's creating code smell.

An alternative design pattern that might serve useful is the [Builder pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern).  The wiki page examples aren't that great, but you should read the [Effective Java](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/effective/) section about Builders.  A builder will help create an immutable object constructed with required and/or optional parameters by chaining mutator methods together and calling a private constructor via a builder method:

```
public class MyClass {

    private final String string1;
    private final String string2;
    private final int int1;
    private final int int2;

    private MyClass(Builder builder) {
        this.string1 = builder.string1;
        this.string2 = builder.string2;
        this.int1 = builder.int1;
        this.int2 = builder.int2;
    }

    public String getString1() {
        return string1;
    }

    public String getString2() {
        return string2;
    }

    public int getInt1() {
        return int1;
    }

    public int getInt2() {
        return int2;
    }

    public static class Builder {
        private String string1;
        private String string2;
        private int int1;
        private int int2;

        // set required parameters in the constructor
        public Builder() { }

        public Builder string1(String string1) {
            this.string1 = string1;
            return this;
        }

        public Builder string2(String string2) {
            this.string2 = string2;
            return this;
        }

        public Builder int1(int int1) {
            this.int1 = int1;
            return this;
        }

        public Builder int2(int int2) {
            this.int2 = int2;
            return this;
        }

        public MyClass build() {
            return new MyClass(this);
        }
    }
}
```

You would construct an object like this:

```
MyClass myClass = new MyClass.Builder().string1("sample1").string2("sample2").int1(1).int2(2).build();
```

Or (using the same class)

```
MyClass myClass = new MyClass.Builder().string1("sample1").int1(1).build();
```

These are horrible method names, but I'm going off your hypothetical scenario.

Answer (score 3):

What you're describing is a [type-safe heterogeneous list](http://apocalisp.wordpress.com/2008/10/23/heterogeneous-lists-and-the-limits-of-the-java-type-system/).

[Here's one I wrote earlier](http://www.google.com/codesearch/p?hl=en#COL-LTKK9OQ/trunk/src/main/fj/data/hlist/HList.java).

Comment: the call site is quite ugly when you have 3 or 4 arguments, `MyClass<X<Integer,X<Integer,X<String,END>>>> instance3` and `instance3.call(x(1,x(2,x("test",END))))`. I like my Tuple idea better

Comment: The reservation is in place but I still think this is not a bad idea at all! I will consider using this. There might be many many parameters when we speak of a prepared statement and simplicity is a consideration here.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this :

Class type : `MyClass <List<?>>`

Comment: That was my first thought too, but it doesn't allow type-safe heterogenous list elements - which is ultimately the crux of the question.

Answer (score 0):

You have to be content with `myMethod(Object...)`. Instances of `MyClass` are not even aware of the parameter types at runtime.